# how to apply same id and function to multiple rows in javascipt

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-table

I write code of html and javascript in which when i click on button it add a new row.It is working fine now i have to find total by multiplying quantity and cost.It works for first row but if i add more rows it not work

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    
      <thead>
        
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>Batch No</th>
        <th>Remarks</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Cost Per Piece</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </thead>
        

    <tbody id="tbody">
</tbody>
<center><button type="button" name=""  onclick="additem()" class="btn btn-success"> Add</button></center></td>
```

and javascript code is

```
 function additem() { 
x++;
  var html="<tr";
      html += "<td><center>"+x+"</center></td>";
      html += "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='product_name'></td>";
      html += "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='batch_no'></td>";
      html += "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='remarks'></td>";
      html += "<td><input type='number' class='form-control' oninput='calculate()'  id='qty' name='total_qty'></td>";
      html += "<td><input type='number' class='form-control'  oninput='calculate()' id='cost' name='cost'></td>";
      html += "<td><input type='number' class='form-control'   id='total'  name='total' readonly></td>";
       html += "<td><button type='button' id='btn' class='btn btn-danger'><i class='fa fa-remove'></i></button></td>";
      html += "</tr>"; 
      document.getElementById("tbody").insertRow().innerHTML= html;
}
```

Comment: id's must be unique in HTML - but as you haven't shown this `find total by multiplying quantity and cost` function, can't help you fix it

Comment: where is calculate function?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a dynamic id on these inputs using `x` variable:
Check out this [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/pshaddel/d9tcrxfn/22/)

```js
let x = 0;
function additem() {
x++;
  var html=`<tr;
      <td><center>${x}</center></td>
      <td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='product_name'></td>
      <td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='batch_no'></td>
      <td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='remarks'></td>
      <td><input id='qty${x}' type='number' class='form-control' oninput='calculate(${x})'  id='qty' name='total_qty'></td>
      <td><input id='cost${x}' type='number' class='form-control'  oninput='calculate(${x})' id='cost' name='cost'></td>
      <td><input type='number' class='form-control'   id='total${x}'  name='total' readonly></td>
      <td><button type='button' id='btn' class='btn btn-danger'><i class='fa fa-remove'></i></button></td>
      </tr>`; 
      document.getElementById("tbody").insertRow().innerHTML= html;
}

function calculate(x) {
  const qty = document.getElementById(`qty${x}`).value;
  const cost = document.getElementById(`cost${x}`).value;
  const totalElem = document.getElementById(`total${x}`);
  totalElem.value = qty * cost
}
```

Comment: wait let me check it

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a unique id for each row and get the element by unique Id. Something like this.

```
let x = 0;
    function additem() {
       
        x++;
        var html = "<tr";
        html += "<td><center>" + x + "</center></td>";
        html += "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='product_name'></td>";
        html += "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='batch_no'></td>";
        html += "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='remarks'></td>";
        html += "<td><input id='qty_" + x + "' type='number' class='form-control' oninput='calculate(" + x + ")'  id='qty' name='total_qty'></td>";
        html += "<td><input id='cost_" + x + "' type='number' class='form-control'  oninput='calculate(" + x + ")' id='cost' name='cost'></td>";
        html += "<td><input id='total_" + x + "' type='number' class='form-control'   id='total'  name='total' readonly></td>";
        html += "<td><button type='button' id='btn' class='btn btn-danger'><i class='fa fa-remove'></i></button></td>";
        html += "</tr>";
        document.getElementById("tbody").insertRow().innerHTML = html;
    }
    function calculate(x) {
        let qty;
        let cost
        if (document.getElementById('qty_' + x))
            qty = document.getElementById('qty_' + x).value;

        if (document.getElementById('cost_' + x))
            cost = document.getElementById('cost_' + x).value;

        let total = qty * cost;
        if (document.getElementById('total_' + x))
            document.getElementById('total_' + x).value = total;
    }
```